# In SQL Server, how to add new login, new Users with parameters?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Pretty straight forward stuff here or so I thought.

```
DECLARE @NewUser varchar(100)

set @NewUser = "[domain\first.last]"

USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  Login [domain\first.last]    Script Date: 3/15/2022 4:51:57 PM ******/
CREATE LOGIN [domain\first.last] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[adventureWorks], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
GO


USE [adventureWorks]
GO


/****** Object:  User [domain\first.last]    Script Date: 3/15/2022 4:52:10 PM ******/
CREATE USER [domain\first.last] FOR LOGIN [domain\first.last] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [domain\first.last]
GO
```

I'm getting an error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Invalid columnn name '[domain\first.last]'.

What am I doing wrong with the variable declaration here?

Comment: Never in a million years if I was searching for help with SQL login script would I have clicked on a result with the name of "What is the difference between single and double quotes in SQL". The vote down makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In T-SQL, double quotes (`"`) are not string delimiters, they're used as identifiers (though most prefer `[square brackets]`). For string delimiters you need to use single quotes (`'`):

```
SET @NewUser = '[domain\first.last]';
```

But if you expect to be able to use that later, e.g.

```
DROP LOGIN @NewUser;
```

...many of those commands don't accept parameters like that. You'll need to construct them using dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @newUser nvarchar(255) = N'domain\first.last';
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'DROP LOGIN $l$;';
SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, N'$l$', QUOTENAME(@newUser));
PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: I neglected to remove the drop statements. That was my query editor so I could rerun the script for testing. Sorry for that confusion.

Comment: @HPWD It was just an example; the point is the same: you can't say `CREATE LOGIN @variable...` either.